# Gmail shortcut keys overridden by DevTools shortcut keys

Tags: gmail, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I can't get Gmail shortcut keys to perform the Gmail actions because (I think) the DevTools actions for that shortcut are performed instead. For instance, to mark an email as read is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, but this opens a DevTools inspection window. This inspection window opens on any page, not just the Gmail page, so I believe it is Chrome.

I have enabled keyboard shortcuts in Gmail settings.
I have gone to Chrome > settings > extensions and turned off developer mode. 
I have restarted Chrome after doing this.

I can't be the only one who has this trouble, but I cannot find any reference to it elsewhere. Any further help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are pressing wrong hotkeys...

- **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>**+**<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>**+**<kbd>i</kbd>** = DevTools
- **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>**+**<kbd>i</kbd>** = Gmail's "Mark as read"

> [image: 4]

**[https://support.google.com/mail/](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6594?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)**